# SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler deprecated but suggested in the Kafka Binder Reference Guide

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

The Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder Reference Guide states that, in a batch consumer, a SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler can be configured to implement a retry functionality.
SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler, however, is deprecated in favor of DefaultErrorHandler.
So what is the correct way to get a repeat behavior in a batch consumer of Spring Cloud Stream Kafka?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Legacy Error Handlers and Their Replacements](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#legacy-eh).

> SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler

> No replacement, use DefaultErrorHandler with an infinite BackOff.

However, there are better ways to handle errors with batch listeners; see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

The SCSt documentation should be updated; I suggest you open an issue there https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues